# react dropdown sorting returns random value everytime, How can i get the required value?

Tags: reactjs, sorting

[here i am trying to add sorting filters but its not returning the right value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Cbfp.png)

I want sorting to return data matches to  option value, currently its giving random data

Comment: You’re mutating state. sort mutates state

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.